# "has not asked" and "has not answered" links to /questions instead of /help

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

When a user has no questions or no answers, the Answers and Questions sections will show something like this:

> This user has not [asked](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) any questions

Note the "asked" links to `/questions` instead of `/help`: (Same applies for "answered" in Answers)

> [image]

While the browser is being redirected to [the proper page](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and it's not a broken link, this is just a useless hop in my opinion.

Can it please be changed to the actual link?